# /dev/sda4 a file system with errors, check forced

Tags: 21.04

The problem has been recurring and every time I run  `fsck /dev/sda4` it fixes the issue. However, the problem keeps recurring.

> `/dev/sda4 contains a file system with errors check forced`
>
> `fsck exited with status code 4`
>
> `/dev/sda4: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY.`
>
> `the root file system on /dev/sda4 requires a manual fsck`
>
> `(initimafs) [10.372378] irq 9: nobody cared:(try booting with the "irqpoll" option`
>
> `[10.373325] handlers:`
>
> `[10.373635][<000000000153ecof>] acpi_irq`
>
> `Disabling IRQ#9`

Comment: Not enough detail.  Likely you are not shutting down the computer correctly or yanking out a removable drive without ejecting it first.   Alternately, the drive may be failing and silently corrupting data.  Describe the type of drive and how you shut down your system or remove the drive or whatever and add it to your answer.  Try running `smartctl -a /dev/sda`

Comment: Without more specific information, all I can guess is "dying disk". Make backups, prepare to replace the disk.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I check the SMART status of a SSD or HDD on current versions of Ubuntu 14.04 through 20.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/528072/how-can-i-check-the-smart-status-of-a-ssd-or-hdd-on-current-versions-of-ubuntu-1)